# Trigger function is not working in chrome?

Tags: jquery, html

I have used trigger function for triggering the text box to enable the another function. But it is not working in chrome.Please help me on this.

```
function add_bodyclass(){
        jQuery('body').addClass('noscroll');
        jQuery('.orig').val(' ').trigger('keyup');
    }
```

Comment: Share the HTML and relevant JS code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write some code as below in chrome's console, and then it will print Event per second.
    
    `$('.orig').off('keyup').on('keyup', function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.orig').val(new Date().getTime()).trigger('keyup');
    }, 1000);`

ps: html code is:
    
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" class="orig">
        </body>
    </html>`

So, ensure your element's `keyup` event has been bound, which has class `orig`, Or could you show your code and the jQuery's version you used.